# language change of whole application JSF automatically

Tags: jsf, localization

I need to change the language of whole project. I am using jsf. In default I used English. Now i need to convert it in Italian and Spanish.

I did it by manually writing in the property class. Just like:
[image]

and in xhtml I need to to put the property by manually.

My question is that, is there any way to convert it automatically?? I mean I just click on Italian, and it will display in italian language.

Comment: This would be a good starting point http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/ google a bit more

Comment: Ya, the link you have given is the same that I appliaed.@Daniel

Comment: does the example work for you ?

Comment: it works... but I need to change property for each every value by manually... I just doing it by auto matically..

Comment: what do you mean " I need to change property for each every value by manually"

Comment: <h:outputText value="#{msg['Register']}" style="color: white"/>
and property of msg is written in the above image. Just see the image I have to write italish language of Register by manually.

Comment: you should have two files, 1 for english myTexts.properties and myTexts_it.properties , where in english you will have Register = Register , and in italian Register = registro , thats all

Comment: @Daniel The attached screenshot (from NetBeans) shows that he has the correct files. My guess is that there are problems in the backing bean

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one file by language (with the correct name)

And fill every - key manually ...

Netbeans help you to display all languages in the same table.

The automaticaly option is Google trad.. it's not good solution.